# Create and use more than one Walker_Nav_Menu on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress theme comes with one walker_Nav_menu. I am trying to create more than one Walker_Nav_menu so I duplicated it:

```
class atsnav_menu_1 extends Walker_Nav_menu {
 // code....
}
```

and

```
class ats_nav_menu_2 extends Walker_Nav_menu {
 // code....
}
```

Then in my header.php file, I used the codes below to display the menus in different sections.

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'        => 'navbar',
    'container'             => false,
    'menu_class'            => '',
    'fallback_cb'           => '__return_false',
    'items_wrap'            => '<ul id="%1$s" class="darkmenu">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'                 => 2,
    'walker'                => new ats_nav_menu_1()
  ) );
?>

<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'        => 'navbar',
    'container'             => false,
    'menu_class'            => '',
    'fallback_cb'           => '__return_false',
    'items_wrap'            => '<ul id="%1$s" class="sidemenu">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'                 => 2,
    'walker'                => new ats_nav_menu_2()
  ) );
?>
```

But this works only if I use only one of the two - ats_nav_menu_1 or ats_nav_menu_2. If I added both, none of them works.
Is it possible to do this in WordPress or did I miss something here? Please show me.

My goal is to show the same menu as vertical and as horizontal on the same page with different customization in terms of levels and other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer. The code was missing a menu id parameter `'menu_id'  => ''` which I added to one of the as shown below:

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'        => 'navbar',
    'container'             => false,
    'menu_id'               => 'mobilenav',
    'menu_class'            => '',
    'fallback_cb'           => '__return_false',
    'items_wrap'            => '<ul id="%1$s" class="sidemenu">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'                 => 2,
    'walker'                => new ats_nav_menu_2()
  ) );
?>
```

That resolves it.